# Model selection with beta and quassi families using gamm4

Tags: r, mixed-models, gam

I have two responses which conform to `beta` (also known as `betar`) and `Poisson` families, and I am looking into fitting additive mixed-models with `beta` and quasi-families (count data is over-dispersed), respectively.

I am aware that I could use `gamm` function from `mgcv` package which accepts both `beta` and quassi-families, however I am considering that it uses PQL, and the `AIC` reported is not useful for comparing models - which is the primary objective of my analyses.

In the case of the count response, I am aware that `QAIC` has been used for ranking/comparing overdispersed mixed models but I cannot find anything that says this it is appropriate for overdispersed GAMM.

I understand these are potentially two questions in one but they both have a common theme of model selection with extended families and potentially have different solutions. Below I provide reproducible examples for each case.

```
##generate data
library(gamm4)
library(mgcv)
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,scale=2)
dat<-subset(dat, select=c(x0,x1,x2,x3,f) )
dat$g <- as.factor(sample(1:20,400,replace=TRUE))#random factor
dat$yb<-runif(400)#yb ranges between 0-1 hence fitted with beta family
dat$f <- dat$f + model.matrix(~ g-1)%*%rnorm(20)*2
dat$yp <- rpois(400,exp(dat$f/7))#y2 is counts hence poisson family

#beta family example with gamm function (this works - however not sure if the subsequent model comparisons are valid!) 
m1b<-    gamm(yb~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family=betar(link='logit'),data=dat,random=list(g=~1))
m2b<-gamm(yb~s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family=betar(link='logit'),data=dat,random=list(g=~1))
m3b<-gamm(yb~s(x0)+s(x2)+s(x3),family=betar(link='logit'),data=dat,random=list(g=~1))

#AIC to compare models  
AIC(m1b,m2b,m3b)

#try the same using gamm4 (ideally)- it obviously fails with beta family.
m<-gamm4(yb~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family=betar(link='logit'),data=dat,random = ~ (1|g)) 

##Example with quassi family - yp response is overdispersed count data (may not be overdispered in this example
#example using gamm function
m1p<-gamm(yp~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family = quasipoisson,data=dat,random=list(g=~1))
m2p<-gamm(yp~s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family = quasipoisson,data=dat,random=list(g=~1))
m3p<-gamm(yp~s(x0)+s(x2)+s(x3),family = quasipoisson,data=dat,random=list(g=~1))

#AIC to compare models
AIC(m1p,m2p,m3p)

#again the example with using gamm4 function will not work as it doesnt accept quassi falimies 
m<-gamm4(yp~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family = quasipoisson,data=dat,random = ~ (1|g))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Based on http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/VGAM/man/betaR.html it looks like the "betar" family is a scaled beta.  I have some thoughts about this, but I'd like to see an improved question first.  I think the short answer is "no"; you're trying to combine (1) mixed models (random effects); (2) scaled-beta distribution; (3) generalized additive models (possibly with *penalized* regression splines).

Comment: @Ben Bolker I hope my question now conforms to the list requirements and I have also provided reproducible examples. Yes, I am trying to combine 1,2 and 3 as you have listed, you are right 3 has penalized regression splines but have not added those to my reproducible code above. Keen to hear your workaround to these.

Comment: I didn't realize `betar` was from `mgcv` - it's a regular Beta (parameterized by location & scale), not a scaled Beta, which makes things a tiny bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of questions here, but I'll try to tackle them.  Basically, you want to fit parametric statistical models with

- random effects (`nlme`, `lme4`)
- distributions from the exponential family ... (`MASS::glmmPQL`, `lme4::glmer`)
- ... with overdispersion ...
- ... or distributions beyond the exponential family such as the Beta distribution (`VGAM`, `betareg`)
- additive models/splines (`splines`) ...
- ... or *penalized regression splines*, which automatically adjust the complexity of the smooth terms
- ... with a real likelihood model rather than a marginal or quasi-likelihood model (e.g. GEEs, PQL), so you can do classic inference

Each of the specified issues above adds 1 or more "difficulty points" to a model-fitting exercise ... usually once your score goes beyond about +3 or so, you have to find a way to compromise or take shortcuts on some of the things you want.  You've correctly identified `gamm` and `gamm4` as doing some of the stuff you want, but you can't get everything.  Some suggestions:

### Overdispersion

One way to handle overdispersion is with an *observation-level random effect*, e.g.

```
dat$obs <- factor(seq(nrow(dat)))
m <- gamm4(yp~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),
           family = poisson,data=dat,random = ~ (1|g)+(1|obs))
```

Another alternative is to adjust the overdispersion yourself, if you think that makes sense, e.g.:

```
m0 <- gamm4(yp~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family = poisson,data=dat,random = ~ (1|g))
```

First compute overdispersion:

```
(phi <- sum(residuals(m0$gam,type="pearson")^2/df.residual(m0$gam)))
## [1] 1.003436
```

(if we repeat this exercise with `m0$mer` instead we get 0.9939696: the result is almost exactly equal to 1 because we generated data from a Poisson distribution in the first place ...)

```
(qaic <- -2*logLik(m0$mer)/phi + 2*lme4:::npar.merMod(m0$mer))
```

**N.B.** I am **guessing that it makes sense to construct the likelihoods, etc. from the individual components of a gamm4 fit in this way; use at your own risk**

### Alternative distributions

The `glmmADMB` and `glmmTMB` packages (both off-CRAN but findable via Google ...) can both handle mixed Beta models.  They can't do penalized regression splines, but you can use regular splines via `splines::ns()` or `splines::bs()` (but you do have to decide on the appropriate level of complexity -- maybe you can guess from preliminary `gamm` or `mgcv` fits ...)

```
library(glmmADMB)
library(splines)
m3b <- glmmadmb(yb~ns(x0,2)+ns(x1,2)+ns(x2,5)+ns(x3,2)+(1|g),
       family="beta",link="logit",data=dat)
```

The `glmmTMB` package can *in principle* do this:

```
library(glmmTMB)
m2b <- glmmTMB(yb~ns(x0,2)+ns(x1,2)+ns(x2,5)+ns(x3,2)+(1|g),
       family=list(family="beta",link="logit"),data=dat)
```

but the package is in development and the current set of results don't make sense -- so I might hesitate to use it at this point.

Comment: This is a great work-around for the two problems as described. I have ended up using this suggestion for my analyses. Just as an extended description of my data: the 0-1 bounded data is artificially created by transforming the actual data with a lower and upper bound using the methods described in :Zimprich, D. (2010). doi:10.1080/15427600903578136. This allows me to then model my response as Beta family using glmmADMB (considering a relatively newer glmmTMB is still under development).